# Background Task 45248 (“GDTStorage”) Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having this log after some time in my flutter app and this is quite alarming since i have no idea what is it :

```
[BackgroundTask] Background Task 45248 (“GDTStorage”), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.
```

Can someone please have an explanation ?

I am using many packages, including the `camera` in case this is related.

Thanks a lot in advance